# TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach

I am trying to fetch data from MDB database to display movies. Initially I have implemented a click event to call data and no errors were found. Until this happened!

[image]

And this is code:

```
this.performSearch()
    }
    performSearch() {
        console.log("Perform search using moviedb")
        const urlString = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=avengers&api_key=1b5adf76a72a13bad99b8fc0c68cb085"
        $.ajax({urlString,
            success: (searchResults) => {
            console.log("Fetched data successfully")
                // console.log(searchResults)
                const results = searchResults.results

                var movieRows = []

                results.forEach((movie) => {
                  console.log(movie.title)

                });
                  const movie = <MovieRow movie={movie}/>
                  movieRows.push(movie)

                this.setState({rows: movieRows})
```

Comment: so results is not defined... look what is returned. `console.log(searchResults)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) Clearly, `searchResults.results` is `undefined.` So that's what you should debug.

Comment: @JosephD. - "From," you mean. And indeed, that's one way this can happen, if `searchResults` is a string that needs parsing (JSON or otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You have no results.  To protect against this you can change

```
const results = searchResults.results
```

to

```
const results = searchResults.results ? searchResults.results : []
```

Comment: I have tried that also, and i get this: 
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'movie' before initialization

Comment: That's because of this line `const movie = <MovieRow movie={movie}/>`.  You're defining `movie`, but using it as part of the definition.  Comment out that line and the one below and it will work as expected (at least as far as the console.log())

Comment: I have done that exactly what you said, and there is no problem now. It works, there is no errors in console. Thanks

Comment: No problem!  If you could +1 & accept the answer in would be much appreciated :)

Comment: No problem!! :)